# Django Jquery UI Slider Filtering via Ajax

Tags: ajax, django, jquery-ui, filtering, django-queryset

I've tried to make a price filter on a ListView. The filter is being passed as an ajax slider on the event of stop in the jquery ui slider. To get the results I've overridden the get_queryset() function. The weird thing is get_queryset() won't give new results after the ajax request, even though the IF statement inside the get_queryset() executes as I can print the price variable in the console. What am I doing wrong ? :S

The ajax request still gives products for the Product.objects.all() result instead of Product.objects.filter(price=0)

Ive also tried to put the product_list into get_context_data() as context['procuct_list'] so it would override the results of the get_queryset() but that did not work either

**!UPDATE!**
The url seems to filter when I send a get request through the address bar, but it just doesn't work through the ajax call??

**It seems not to work just with ajax why?**

class ShopView

```
class ShopView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "shop/shop.html"
    context_object_name = "product_list"

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ShopView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['category_list'] = Category.objects.all()
    return context

def get_queryset(self):
    price = self.request.GET.get('price')
    if price:
        print price #This gets printed
        return Product.objects.filter(price=0) #But this fails!?
    else:
        return Product.objects.all()
```

The Jquery UI slider

```
$(function() {
    var priceSlider = ".price-slider";
    var priceMin = "span.min-price";
    var priceMax = "span.max-price";
    $(priceSlider).slider({
        range: "min",
        value:5,
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $(priceMax).html( ui.value + "€");
        },
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            var price = ui.value;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: "price=" + price,
                cache: false,
            });
        }
    });
```

The for cycle for rendering products

```
{% for product in product_list %}
    {% include "shop/product.html" %}
{% endfor %}
```

The product html itself

```
<div class="product-price">
    <p>{{ product.price }}€</p>
</div>
...etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, stupid mistake, I wasn't doing anything with the AJAX request afterwards.

```
success: function(data) {
    $("body").html(data);
}
```